# Eliminate ssh login delay

Tags: ssh, login

I would like to remove the delay that occurs with ssh when logging in from my intranet but retain the delay when logging in from the internet.

Is this possible?

Comment: May I ask **why** you would ever want a delay, on either end?

Comment: You would want a delay when accessing from the internet to make brute force attacks very slow.

Comment: is this what you loking for http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050503190955329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem often occurs when reverse dns lookup enabled by SSDH. Try to use 'UseDNS no' in config.

Comment: hahahahr, so now intranet AND internet have the same delay? :))

Answer (score 0):

use ssh-keys to authenticate yourself from the intranet machines.

your password-based authentication runs on the client against the keys you are using. once that is done, there will be no delay when authenticating against the server (sshd_config MaxStartups)